# C++ On Demand Creation

Tags: c++

I'm reading a book where the following code appears.

```
TTextInBuffer::TTextInBuffer(const char *pInputFileName, TAbortCode ac)
: pFileName(new char[strlen(pInputFileName) + 1])
```

`pFileName` is declared as a const char, so I'm assuming that the second line creates a new char in `pFileName`.  I would just like to know the specifics of what is happening. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this constructor is called, the initializer list here is executed:

```
: pFileName(new char[strlen(pInputFileName) + 1])
```

The `strlen()` call finds the length of the `pInputFileName` string based on its contents. It basically walks it as a char array until it finds a `NULL` and then returns the result. This is being done in order to compute the space needed for the new string within `pFileName`.

The `+ 1` is there to make sure there's room for the extra `NULL` termination character at the end.

Finally, whatever number pops out of that expression is fed into a memory allocation call using the keyword `new`. This gets memory dynamically allocated on the heap where the string data will end up. The `new` call returns the address of where that memory has been allocated, and that is passed to the `pFileName` pointer variable so that it will point to it.

So, to summarize:

1. The length of `pInputFileName` is computed
2. The computed length is increased by 1 to cater for NULL in the copy
3. `new` is called to request space for the copy
4. The address returned by `new` is assigned to `pFileName`

The one thing that's missing from your code is the actual copy over of the contents of the input string to the destination, but perhaps that happens within the constructor body (between the `{` and `}` characters).

Answer (score 0):

Second line allocates memory area (array of `char`s) by calling operator `new[]`.

Argument of `new` is size of array to allocate. So, in this snippet the length is set to length of string `pInputFileName` + 1. This `+ 1` serves to fit null character that is used in C and C++ to determine where strings ends.